# g++ can't infer template types for functional map implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, functional-programming

As an exercise (note that I'm aware of std::transform), I'm trying to implement the map function typically found on functional languages such as Haskell in C++. This is the code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

template<typename A, typename B>
std::vector<B> functional_map (std::function<B(A)> func, std::vector<A> v)
{
    std::vector<B> result(v.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        result[i] = func(v[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Despite that, the compiler is unable to correctly infer the template types for functional_map when called like this:

```
int square (int x) {return x*x;}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    std::vector<int> v2 = functional_map(square, v);
    for (int y : v2) {
        std::cout << y << " ";
    }
}
```

This is the generated error by G++:

```
functional_cpp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
functional_cpp.cpp:18:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘functional_map(int (&)(int), std::vector<int>&)’
     vector<int> v2 = functional_map(square, v);
                                   ^
functional_cpp.cpp:6:44: note: candidate: template<class A, class B> std::vector<B> functional_map(std::function<B(A)>, std::vector<A>)
 template<typename A, typename B> vector<B> functional_map (function<B(A)> func, vector<A> v) {
                                            ^
functional_cpp.cpp:6:44: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
functional_cpp.cpp:18:35: note:   mismatched types ‘std::function<B(A)>’ and ‘int (*)(int)’
     vector<int> v2 = functional_map(square, v);
```

Apparently, g++ is failing to match a regular function pointer to the `std::function` type, which is made to make a consistent typing for all functions in C++. Note that changing square by a lambda also fails compiling (but the type being matched against changes from `nt (&)(int)` to `lambda(int)`.

That being said, changing `functional_map` to `functional_map<int, int>` successfully compiles and executes with correct results.

Why is this happening? And how can I fix my implementation so the compiler will infer the template types?

*EDIT* To avoid confusion with `std::map`, as suggested in the comments I changed the name "map" with "functional_map" in all the question.

Comment: `using namespace std` and declaring names like `map` and `list` seem to be a recipe for disaster. Stop abusing namespaces already and whack whoever told you to say `using namespace std` around the head a few times.

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm well aware of that, thanks for your feedback. As I mention in my post this is a quick exercise, so I'm not bothering in being stl-friendly, I just wanted to avoid typing std:: a bunch of times, take it as a dirty hack if you must. Anyway, maybe I should change my question to not confuse future readers?

Comment: I'm not so bothered about confusing readers as I am about *miseducating* users. Think of the poor innocent  who happen across your post and have yet one more subliminal message implanted in their malleable brains that this is acceptable code...

Comment: You're right, even if I know the implications of doing that, someone else might not know, I changed my question to fix the issue.

Comment: You didn't but now I have :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to take any callable function object and infer its result type:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename F, typename A,
          typename B = typename std::decay<typename std::result_of<F&(typename std::vector<A>::const_reference)>::type>::type>
std::vector<B> functional_map(F func, const std::vector<A>& v)
{
    std::vector<B> result(v.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)v.size(); ++i)
    {
        result[i] = func(v[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/786a1f15216d84f1)

[`std::result_of<F(Args...)>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) is a type-trait that exploits a combination of the [`std::declval<T>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) function and the [`decltype()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) specifier so as to deduce the result type of a function object of type `F` called with parameters of types `Args...`. That is,

```
typename std::result_of<F&(typename std::vector<A>::const_reference)>::type
```

is equivalent to:

```
decltype(std::declval<F&>()(std::declval<typename std::vector<A>::const_reference>()))
```

which is the same as:

```
decltype(func(v[i]))
```

You don't pay for type-erasure, yet you are still able to get type `B`.

By [`std::decay<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay)'ing the type you are guaranteed it can be stored in a vector (in case the function object returns a reference etc.).

Alternatively, you can declare it as:

```
template <typename F, typename A>
auto functional_map(F func, const std::vector<A>& v)
    -> std::vector<typename std::decay<decltype(func(v[0]))>::type>
{
    using B = typename std::decay<decltype(func(v[0]))>::type;
    std::vector<B> result(v.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)v.size(); ++i)
    {
        result[i] = func(v[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb25beb5e5f028fa)

which is more or less the same.

Comment: Thanks, your code indeed works. But I'm really confused on how you achieved the result. Could you please explain a bit more in detail?

Comment: The second version isn't exactly "the same", since the original version allows you to specify the destination type, which may be handy. Speaking of being handy, a more versatile solution might be to return a magic proxy object with a templated conversion operator so you can construct *any* container from it.

Comment: You can easily modify that solution to allow any container as the argument. (Or at least, many containers). http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c10dd69bd688dfc

Answer (score 1):

Template argument deduction does not consider user-defined conversions.

Make the conversion yourself:

```
vector<int> v2 = functional_map(std::function<int(int)>(square), v);
```

Comment: So basically there's no way my code will work without "casting" to std::function?

Comment: @Setzer22: Nope. Well, `functional_map<int, int>(square, v)` might do it. The underlying problem you're having is that you're trying to take a concept from one language and recreate it verbatim in a completely different language, and inaccurately at that. C++ standard library algorithms tend to work over iterator ranges, not actual containers; you'd find this much easier if you followed that pattern.

Comment: @Setzer22: You could define a different kind of template, perhaps using `std::result_of`... [edit] oh, that's what the other answer proposes already.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree on that, I was just testing how much flexibility C++ allows in this cases, but it seems I'm on the border of what can actually be done in the language at this point. Having said that, it would be nice to have a version working with containers rather than ranges. It's much more comfortable to simply write v rather than v.begin(), v.end().

Comment: Unfortunately if you're looking for brevity you are going to have to sacrifice expressiveness. That's just how C++ is these days: a bloody mess, frankly.